# Why are my descenders being cut off when using CSS @font-face?

Tags: css, font-face

I'm using the Google webfonts API to embed Droid Sans on a page. All is fine, except for the descenders (i.e. the dangly bits on y, g, etc). The latest versions of Firefox, IE and Chrome on my Windows Vista box are all cutting the bottom off.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Droid sans descender test</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:regular,bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <style type="text/css">
  body { font-size: 16px; font-family: "Droid Sans", sans-serif; }
  h1, h2, h3 { margin: 1em 0; font-weight: normal; }
  h1 { font-size: 2em; }
  h2 { font-size: 1.5em; }
  h3 { font-size: 1em; }
 </style>
</head>    
<body>
 <h1>A bug ran under the carpet anyway</h1>
 <h2>A bug ran under the carpet anyway</h2>
 <h3>A bug ran under the carpet anyway</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code looks like this:

[image: Descenders getting cut off]
<sub>(source: [thinkdrastic.net](http://thinkdrastic.net/journal/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/descenders.png))</sub>

I've tried `line-height`, `font-size`, `padding` etc to no avail. I had some success with `font-size-adjust`, but the last time I checked it was Gecko only. Does anybody know of a fix for this?

Comment: Works fine on MacOS WebKit. Have you tried giving a bigger margin?

Comment: Yep. I suspect this is going to be one of those "that's just how Windows does stuff" questions.

Comment: This might just be a copy-paste error, but `font-family: "Droid Sans"sans-serif;` needs a comma.

Comment: @kevingessner Good catch. I ripped out all the fallback fonts for simplicity's sake, but removed a little too much :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With some help from [@adamliptrot](https://web.archive.org/web/20140111124330/https://twitter.com/adamliptrot), I discovered that Droid Sans' descenders are absolutely fine at a few precise pixel sizes: 18, 22 and 27px. I adjusted my em's accordingly:

```
h1 { font-size: 1.6875em; }
h2 { font-size: 1.375em; }
h3 { font-size: 1.125em; }
```

Not ideal, but it works:

[image: The descenders work!]
<sub>(source: [thinkdrastic.net](http://thinkdrastic.net/journal/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/fixed-descenders.png))</sub>

Comment: This probably means things will fail again at any kind of zoom, or on a non-standard resolution display.

Comment: It seems to work fine at various zoom levels. Given that it's only a minor visual glitch that only happens on Windows, and in this case it's an intranet with a fairly homogenous hardware setup I'm not *too* worried. Certainly something to keep an eye on though :)

Comment: Had the same issue with a font 'Walkway' and the magic 1.6875em figure worked for that too...odd systematic fault

Answer (score 5):

*Although your question is in relation to the Google Web Fonts API, the principle of my answer beneath is the same.*

If the descendants are being cut-off when serving a TrueType Font, the most likely cause is that OS/2 metrics are incorrectly set (negatively) on the font.

The values that may need adjustment are WinAscent & WinDescent.

A quick and dirty fix would be to adjust these both to 0.

This can be done using [Font Forge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/). Once the font is opened in FontForge, you can gain access to these parameters via the '[Font Info](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/fontinfo.html)' dialogue.

Comment: This did not seem to work for me.  I successfully changed these metrics in fontforge, but the problem persists.

Comment: Can you send me the font, I'll have a look at why this isn't working.

Comment: This just helped me find a problem with a font I created with MyScriptFont.com. The OS/2 metric was set to a wrong value. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

I have checked the referenced ttf files, and even in windows font viewer the descenders are being cut. Seems more of an issue with the font being served rather than with your styles.

Comment: So they do. I wonder if this is an issue with the fonts or with Windows font rendering?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Font Squirrel, it seems the issue with the sans variant has been sorted, but the issue remains with Font Squirrel's serif variant.

For a fix for the serif variant, go to the Web Font Generator and load the font files you need (do not rely on the package they provide).

Click the 'Expert' radio button, leave all of the settings but under 'Advanced Options' change  the 'Em Square Value' to '2162' and generate the font.

This renders the font properly at **all** sizes

Comment: That did not solve it for me. I had the problem at 14.8-15.2 px (IE) / 15.0 - 15.1 px (Chrome, Firefox) with Open Sans. Even after setting the em square value from 2048 to 2162, that problem persisted. Maybe trying even bigger values might have worked, but I suppose I'll opt for just avoiding the problem range.

Answer (score 1):

we've been having the same problem...we tried using font squirrel. we tried using google web fonts. The font kept cutting off "hanging" letters like g. Also, the google hosted version did not appear as true and clear as the other ones. The font seemed a bit choppy.

Our solution:

We hosted the font ourselves without formatting it for the web. Then we converted the ttf file to an svg, .eot, and .otf, and uploaded those as our fixes for ie and mozilla etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the tip at the top - changing font-size to....

```
h1 { font-size: 1.6875em; }
h2 { font-size: 1.375em; }
h3 { font-size: 1.125em; }
```

doesn't work for you, then add "line-height" to the element that is cutting off the descenders. ``

Comment: Interesting. `line-height` didn't work for me at all, but certain pixel sizes did. Those `em` sizes might not be quite right for you if your base font size is different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but I've had the same problem occur when fonts get substituted. I just wonder if this occurs when say a font substitution replaces a 1024em font with a 1000em font or vice-versa.  I had some major descender cut-off using a 2048em font. Might be worth investigating.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar dilemma and the line-height fix worked for me (i.e. I added this code to the Custom CSS section):

```
h2 { line-height: 140%; }
```