# Italic "g" character right side is getting cut off

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have the following structure for my CSS:

```
index.html
css
--fonts
----roboto
------roboto-italic-demo.html
------roboto-italic-webfont.woff
------roboto-italic-webfont.woff2
------stylesheet.css
--main.css
```

`stylesheet.css` contains the following CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'robotoitalic';
    src: url('roboto-italic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('roboto-italic-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

`roboto-italic-demo.html` is a demo page with the entire alphabet characters displayed using `font-family: 'robotoitalic';`. Here the g appears like it should.

[image]

`main.css` contains the following css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'roboto';
    src: url('fonts/roboto/roboto-bolditalic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/roboto/roboto-bolditalic-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'robototest2';
    src: url('fonts/roboto/roboto-italic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/roboto/roboto-italic-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

`index.html` includes the `main.css` stylesheet. Using `font-family: 'roboto'; font-style: italic;` cuts off the right side of the g character. using `font-family: 'robototest2';` cuts the right side of the g character as well.

[image]

Here's what I tried in order to fix the issue:

- Redownload `roboto-italic-webfont.woff` && `roboto-italic-webfont.woff2`
- Put `"Comic Sans MS"` as a fall back to make sure I was actually using `roboto` or `robototest2`
- Added letter-spacing
- Placed the g character within a span with padding

**edit:**

This question was marked as duplicate. The question linked referred to text protruding from its container, where as this one is about a character being cut-off no matter its position within any tag. For example, this html

```
<p><em>This g is being cut off on its right side</em></p>
```

results in

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296434/html-italic-letters-protrude-from-their-container-and-may-be-cut-by-the-next-co

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, also with Roboto, italic at regular weight. The version of Roboto I was using was self hosted and downloaded from Font Squirrel.

I tried the Google hosted version of Roboto, and it rendered the "g" correctly, so I figured there must be something off with my version of the font. I found this answer on a separate Stack Overflow issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15976457/1786681 which recommended uploading your own ttf of the font to Font Squirrel's webkit generator, selecting the "Expert" option, and leaving all the defaults except changing the "Em Square Value" to "2162". I downloaded the .ttf file of Roboto from Google and went through these steps and voila! My italic "g"s are now rendering beautifully!